# Angularjs comparing elements from two arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one array something like following:

```
$scope.blinkedBoxes=[3,4,1,2,..]
```

**It will have upto 8 elements in total** (elements will be one of the numbers from 1,2,3,4).

Another array is like following:

```
$scope.clickedImages=[2,4,3,1,...]
```

I am building following function:

```
$scope.checkCrossCorrectness = function(array1, array2){}
```

**My requirement is:**

If the first element of `$scope.blinkingBoxes` is 2 (or basically any from 1, 2, 3, 4) then in `$scope.clickedImages` first element can not be 2 (or same as first element of first array), instead could be 1, 3, or 4.
This logic continues for further elements as well (i.e. in first array at second position if 3 comes then in second array second position can be occupied by either 1, 2 or 4)

How can I implement this?

Comment: Uhm, and what should happen if the second array has the same number as the first array in the same index? Should it return true or false, or should it change the arrays, or should it launch a mission to Mars ... or ... it's not really clear what this function is supposed to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont really know if this has anything to do with angular specifically, but from what I can tell a simple forEach loop will do to check equality between the indexes.

Example:

```
$scope.blinkedBoxes = [1, 2 ..] // etc
$scope.clickedImages = [2, 1, ..] // etc

function functionToRunOnClickOrWhatever(){
    $scope.blinkedBoxes.forEach(function(val, index){
        var isEqual = val === $scope.clickedImages[index];

        if(isEqual){
            // do something?
        }
    });
}
```